# How to reduce opacity of custom listview in android

Tags: android

i have a listview of text item,i want reduce opacity(alpha) of listview. when i set alpha then reduce both text and layout color,but my requirment is reduce only background color of listview.. for example
Here is my code....

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    >
<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
   >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
 <!--  <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search Remedy.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/> android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"-->
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
         />
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the alpha at runtime like this

Alpha Values 0-255, 0 means fully transparent, and 255 means fully opaque

```
View backgroundimage = findViewById(R.id.background);
Drawable background = backgroundimage.getBackground();
background.setAlpha(80);
```